# Como concatenar um valor com uma string

Tags: postgresql

Olá, eu preciso criar uma função em postgresql que recebe duas idades e a função retorna as datas de nascimento. Eu estou com dificuldade para fazer o calculo da data de nascimento, já tentei usar interval e outros comandos do tipo data para solucionar esse problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para diminuir 48 anos de uma data:

```
select now() - 48 * interval '1 year';
           ?column?            
-------------------------------
 1968-10-07 20:46:38.699564+00
```

Veja que não é preciso fazer concatenação. Basta multiplicar.

Comment: Muito Obrigado, deu certo!